# Set input file element with file using HTML5 File API

Tags: html, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I am using an input file element to upload file in my JSP page. The user can upload the file by clicking on a button which opens a form with browser's browse button

Now, I want to upload the file by using drag drop feature of HTML5 (as described @ [html5 rocks page](http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)). I am able to extract the file name using File API. Is there a way to load the input file element with the dropped file using File API? (So that I may use the same behavior to upload file)

Answer (score 5):

There's no way to set the value of a `<input type=file>` directly in JS. That action
requires user intervention (and a click on a file picker). However, you can use 
`xhr.send(FormData)` or `xhr.send(File)` to send the files. See my response here:

[HTML5 File API readAsBinaryString reads files as much larger, different than files on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133800/html5-file-api-readasbinarystring-reads-files-as-much-larger-different-than-file/6142797#6142797)

In your drop handler, just pas the `FileList` obtained from `evt.dataTransfer.files` to that `uploadFiles()` helper.

Comment: This is the best way to handle drag and drop uploading, bar none. I made a fiddle, based on ebidel's code, to show it in action. http://jsfiddle.net/chad/Qrfb7/

Answer (score 2):

I was able to set the "files" attribute of the input element with the files property of the dataTransfer object.

document.getElementById("insert input file id").files = evt.dataTransfer.files;

I just tried using getelement.value and it errors.  Set the files property with the files list.

Happy Programming!

Kremnari

Comment: I like this solution. It doesn't work in IE 11 or Firefox though (input.files is a read-only property).

Comment: does it actually submit the file when you post the form?  doesn't look like it for me (Chrome v43)

Answer (score 0):

it is indeed impossible to handle anything client related in javascript. You could however [use the file api to convert the image to base64](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/html5-drag-and-drop-and-file-api-tutorial/). You can then send this value to the server through a form and a hidden input value (or one created with javascript), decode it in php or whatever serverside language you're using, and save it as an image file.