# Trouble uploading binary files using FileReader api

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, file-upload

I'm using FileReader.readAsBinaryString to upload a file using a multipart/form-data POST request to a server.

The file gets sent and the server receives and saves the file.

When I try to open the file on the server I get messages saying that it is corrupted (png images) or I see a blank document (in the case of a pdf). Obviously something is going wrong.

Is there some other encoding that needs to be applied to the data returned in event.target.result in the FileReader.onload handler? Am I missing something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `FormData` instead of reading the file as a binary string and constructing the multipart/form-data request manually. See my response here:
[HTML5 File API readAsBinaryString reads files as much larger, different than files on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133800/html5-file-api-readasbinarystring-reads-files-as-much-larger-different-than-file/6142797#6142797)