# image upload to web service in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, file-upload

I need to upload an image to a webservice from javascript. I have to send a json string an a file(image). In java we have `MultipartEntity`. I have the followig code in java:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost( aWebImageUrl2 );
MultipartEntity entity  = new MultipartEntity( HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE );
// For File parameters
entity.addPart( "picture", new FileBody((( File ) imgPath )));
// For usual String parameters
entity.addPart( "url", new StringBody( aImgCaption, "text/plain", Charset.forName( "UTF-8" )));
post.setEntity( entity );
```

Now I need to do the same image upload in javascript.
But in javaScript I didn't find any equivalent of MultipartEntity. Please Suggest any solutions.

Comment: What are you running server side (PHP, ASP.Net, ...)?

Comment: @Greg, the webservice is using Java and it is a Restful webservice. the webservices are written by some one. I need to access only. I cannot change it.

Answer (score 5):

For uploading images I use either [Valum's ajax upload plugin](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) or [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started) that allows to submit a normal form in an ajax way.

If you will use POST requests then don't forget to use MAX_FILE_SIZE hidden attribute:

`<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="20000000">`

Note that it must precede the file input field. It is in bytes, so this will limit the upload to 20MB. See [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) for details.

Comment: @kommradHomer, I use this only for Opera, for other browsers I use Valum's plugin - the main advantage is that no form is needed - the image is just added with one click.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your Java code is using [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) (what you really should have said then), your code, when augmented with

```
URI aWebImageUrl2 = new URI("http://localhost:1337/");
File imgPath = new File("…/face.png");
final String aImgCaption = "face";
// …
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpClient.execute(post);
```

submits the following example HTTP request (as tested with `nc -lp 1337`, see [GNU Netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/)):

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 990
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=oQ-4zTK_UL007ymPgBL2VYESjvFwy4cN8C-F
Host: localhost:1337
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.2 (java 1.5)

--oQ-4zTK_UL007ymPgBL2VYESjvFwy4cN8C-F
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="picture"; filename="face.png"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

�PNG[…]
```

The simplest solution to do something like this in HTML is, of course, to use a [`FORM` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3) and no or minimal client-side scripting:

```
<form action="http://service.example/" method="POST"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="picture">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

which submits (either when submitted with the submit button or the form object's `submit()` method) the following example request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1337
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 886
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryhC26St5JdG0WUaCi
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://localhost/scripts/test/XMLHTTP/file.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: de-CH,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

------WebKitFormBoundaryhC26St5JdG0WUaCi
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="picture"; filename="face.png"
Content-Type: image/png

�PNG[…]
```

But since you have asked explicitly about a "javascript" solution (there really is [no such programming language](http://PointedEars.de/es-matrix)), I presume that you want to have more client-side control over the submit process.  In that case, you can use the [W3C File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) and [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Ajax) or [XMLHttpRequest2](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/) APIs as provided by recent browsers (*not* the programming languages):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function isHostMethod(obj, property)
  {
    if (!obj)
    {
      return false;
    }

    var t = typeof obj[property];
    return (/\bunknown\b/i.test(t) || /\b(object|function)\b/i.test(t) && obj[property]);
  }

  var global = this;

  function handleSubmit(f)
  {
    if (isHostMethod(global, "XMLHttpRequest"))
    {
      try
      {
        var input = f.elements["myfile"];
        var file = input.files[0];
        var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        x.open("POST", f.action, false);  // ¹

        try
        {
          var formData = new FormData();
          formData.append("picture", file);
          x.send(formData);
          return false;
        }
        catch (eFormData)
        {
          try
          {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (evt) {
              var boundary = "o" + Math.random();
              x.setRequestHeader(
                "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
              x.send(
                  "--" + boundary + "\r\n"
                + 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="picture"; filename="' + file.name + '"\r\n'
                + 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n'
                + evt.target.result
                + '\r\n--' + boundary + '--\r\n');
            };
            reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
            return false;
          }
          catch (eFileReader)
          {
          }
        }
      }
      catch (eFileOrXHR)
      {
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
</script>
<form action="http://service.example/" method="POST"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      onsubmit="return handleSubmit(this)">
  <input type="file" name="myfile">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This approach tries to use the XMLHttpRequest API. If that fails, the function returns `true`, so `true` is returned to the event handler (see the attribute value), and the form is submitted the usual way (the latter might not work with your Web service; test before use by disabling script support).

If XMLHttpRequest can be used, it is "tested"² if the file input has a `files` property and the object referred to by that has a `0` property (referring to the first selected `File` for that form control, if supported).

If yes, the XMLHttpRequest2 API is tried, which `send()` method [can take a reference to a `FormData`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#the-send-method) and do all the multi-part magic by itself. If the XMLHttpRequest2 API is not supported (which should throw an exception), the File API's `FileReader` is tried, which can read the contents of a `File` as binary string (`readAsBinaryString()`); if that is successful (`onload`), the request is prepared and submitted. If one of those approaches seemingly worked, the form is not submitted (`return false`).

Example request submitted with this code using the FormData API:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1337
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 887
Origin: http://localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryLIXsjWnCpVbD8FVA
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost/scripts/test/XMLHTTP/file.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: de-CH,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

------WebKitFormBoundaryLIXsjWnCpVbD8FVA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="picture"; filename="face.png"
Content-Type: image/png

�PNG[…]
```

The example request looks slightly different when the FileReader API was used instead (just as proof of concept):

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1337
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1146
Origin: http://localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=o0.9578036249149591
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost/scripts/test/XMLHTTP/file.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: de-CH,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

--o0.9578036249149591
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="picture"; filename="face.png"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

PNG[…]
```

Notice that the XMLHttpRequest2, FormData and File API are having only *Working Draft* status and so are still in flux. Also, this approach works if the resource submitted from and the resource submitted to are using the same protocol, domain, and port number; you may have to deal with and [work around the Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Cross-domain_requests). Add feature tests and more exception handling as necessary.

Also notice that the request made using `FileReader` is larger with the same file and misses the leading character, as indicated in the question referred to by Frits van Campen. This may be due to a (WebKit) bug, and you may want to remove this alternative then; suffice it for me to say that the `readAsBinaryString()` method is *deprecated* already in the File API Working Draft in favor of `readAsArrayBuffer()` which should use [Typed Arrays](http://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/).

See also ["Using files from web applications"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications).

¹ Use `true` for asynchronous handling; this avoids UI blocking, but requires you to do processing in the event listener, and you will always have to cancel form submission (even if XHR was unsuccessful).

² If the property access is not possible, an exception will be thrown. If you prefer a real test, implement (additional) feature-testing (instead), and be aware that not everything can be safely feature-tested.

Answer (score 0):

you can actually invoke a service using javascript, there is a sample code for this [here](http://www.guru4.net/articoli/javascript-soap-client/demo/en.aspx)

if your requirement is to upload the image and make the webservice call from JS then it could be tricky.

you can simply upload the image to a server and have the server call the webservice, there are loads of tools which helps you to [upload a file to a server](http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/).

Comment: Anantha Sharma,I have a webservice which is written by some one in java and a Restfull webservice. I have to upload the image and json message from a html page using javascript directly to webservice (I cannot use any server side script). The uploaded image and json message I need to send as multiple parts (MultipartEntity) with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

MultipartEntity sounds like `Multipart/form-data`.

You can use a regular `XMLHttpRequest` to make a POST request. You can use the HTML 5 `FormData` to build your `Multipart/form-data` request.

Here is an example: [HTML5 File API readAsBinaryString reads files as much larger, different than files on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133800/html5-file-api-readasbinarystring-reads-files-as-much-larger-different-than-fil/6142797#6142797)

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before and it works, using HTML5's canvas element. I'll be using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) here. I'm assuming a generic image of 300px by 300px.

First, add a hidden canvas to your page :

```
$("body").append('<canvas id="theCanvas" style="display:none" width="300px" height="300px"></canvas>');
```

Then, load the image to the canvas :

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('theCanvas');  
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = "/path/to/image.jpg";  
context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, 300, 300);
```

Now, you can access what's on the canvas as a data string and post it to the webservice using jQuery's post function :

```
$.post("path/to/service", {'image':canvas.toDataURL("image/png"), 'url':'caption'},  function(file){               
    //Callback code
});
```

Comment: this sends a base64 encoded png file which has some additional headers in front so it's probably useless, unless the webservice supports the dataURL format.

Comment: that's true. You could strip those out by passing this to a custom php function, then using curl to send it to the web service.

Comment: What about doing this: var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var yourImageData =  dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");