# DOC to PDF conversion using Jersey framework

Tags: jersey, convertapi

I am building a simple Jersey application which converts DOC to PDF. I am using a API from  http://www.convertapi.com . I would like to know how to send my file to the API.

Comment: this should be simple HTTP POST request. You can provide the parameters and inspect the request from browser's dev tools /network tab

Comment: The API has a required parameter called FILE it takes a binary input. I am not finding what to specify in that field. Can you please go through the convertapi.com website. It would give you a brief idea of the parameters and the API

Comment: it is sending image as http POST using multipart form. you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178674/image-upload-to-web-service-in-javascript this link on code/plugin in javascript for sending image as multipart form